# .htaccess redirect css to php

Tags: php, css, .htaccess, redirect

I have multiple css files in a directory (style0.css, style1.css etc..) How can I redirect a request to these css files with htaccess so that a php can process the requested css file.
ex. `/styles/style0.css -> /includes/compressor.php?i=style0.css` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*).css$ /includes/compressor.php?i=$1.css [L]
```

These .htAccess command activate the RewriteEngine. This will let you analyse the request URL and execute the one you want into the server. The second line take all URL that end with .css and will take the file name to insert it as a parameter (like you wanted in your example).

For example:

http://localhost/styles/style1.css will go to

http://localhost/includes/compressor.php?i=style1.css

The L flag will tell Apache to stop processing the rewrite rules for that request.

Comment: would you explain a bit please? what does the [L] do?

Comment: The L flag will tell Apache to stop processing the rewrite rules for that request.

Answer (score 7):

Add an .htaccess to your css directory with these two lines.  You can now add php code to your css files, and it will be processed :

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .css

php_value default_mimetype "text/css"
```

Comment: Better to use rewriting if possible, since a .css file should contain CSS, not PHP. It's semantically incorrect and annoying to edit, as your editor will try to parse the file as CSS and fail.

Comment: i'm using it in the following way:
my css is singleSheet.css?sheets[]=main.css&sheets[]=rest.css
this allows me to have one sheet, built server side (no @includes)

Comment: I think this is a good idea too and I might use it in the future so +1, but because I only want to compress the css files with php and stuff like that, I would have to copy the same code to all my css files and if I would want to change something I would have to edit all of them.